# Is there a quick way to identify unique keys in a list of variant objects?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to perform a reverse mapping on data that looks like this:

```
{
booleanKey: val,
integerKey: val,
uncommonKey1: val,
},
{
booleanKey: val,
integerKey: val,
uncommonKeyB: val,
}
```

Is there a way to quickly find the names of the uncommon keys?
I.E: `uncommonKey1, uncommonKeyB`

I was looking to use Object.keys(), but I am worried about the property order being inconsistent.

Comment: To discover which keys are present, `Object.keys(obj)` is the right way to go. _"but I am worried about the property order being inconsistent"_. Usually, the order is consistent when you run this in the same environment, but you are right, the order is not garanteed between environments. However, the order might not matter. How do you define "uncommon" keys? Keys which are not present in **all** of the objects?

Comment: If you’re looking for unique key, why is the order of keys important? Also it is a common fallacy to think that there is no guaranteed order to object keys in JS: [there actually is](https://dev.to/frehner/the-order-of-js-object-keys-458d)